# how do i block multiple mouse click over an element in next windows WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have multiple windows in a wpf project.
in any window, i put a control (such as button). as position of controls in all windows is same. i define a MouseLeftButtonUp event for controls in all windows. with click (mouse left button up) on the control, i create and open dialog next window.
for example for first window:

```
Window2 win2 = new Window2 ();
win2.Owner = this;
win2.ShowDialog();
```

but my problem:

if i do double click or triple click on the button of first window, since all position controls in all windows is same, all two or three windows opening as cascading. and i want open only one next window.

thanks for your answers

Comment: You may want to consider allowing this, rather than fixing it.  It's a feature, not a bug!  Your program is simply responding as fast as the user clicks :)  If they double click when trying to do a single action, you could treat that as their fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my comment above.  You may want to consider this to be "by-design", and not fix it.

If you do decide to fix it, you could implement a form of de-bouncing.

- Create some form of global state that all windows can see (such as a field in the application object, or the main window class).
- In that global state, keep the time of the last successful/correct click.  Start off with `DateTime.MinValue` (or whatever it is called).
- On click, grab the current time `DateTime.Now`
- If the time between the current time, and the lass successful click is too short (less than your debounce time.  Maybe `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)`), then don't create a new window
- If the time span is longer than your debounce time, then update the last successful/correct click, and only then open the new window

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered disabled the button initially and enabling a second after the form has loaded? You can do this using a timer.